# Numerical precision of linear 3D texture interpolation on GPU (OpenCL)

Tags: textures, opencl, interpolation, precision

I use GPU to accelerate molecular dynamics, where I store long-range force-field (e.g. electrostatics) in 3D texture.

I found that there is quite large **numerical error ~1.0E-3** when compared to my tri-linear interpolation implemented in C++/CPU. While CPU curve is completely smooth, GPU curve has relative noise level ~1.0E-3. Yes GPU use just single-precission (float32) but, still ~1.0E-3 is much worse than float32 precision (~1.0E-8).

Is this normal? Is there a way to improve accuracy while still using hardware texture interpolation?

**DETAILS:**

OpenCL:

```
__constant sampler_t sampler_1 = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_TRUE | CLK_ADDRESS_REPEAT | CLK_FILTER_LINEAR;
float4 fe = read_imagef( imgCoulomb,  sampler_1, coord );
```

C++ wrapper:

```
p_gpu = clCreateImage3D(context, flags, {CL_RGBA, CL_FLOAT}, nImg[0],nImg[1],nImg[2], 0, 0, p_cpu, &err);
```

System/Setup:

```
GPU: Quadro K2200/PCIe/SSE2
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GPUs frequently take shortcuts for texture interpolation. For example, they might only have 256 steps between values, so if those values are quite far apart, you're not going to get much accuracy. Keep in mind they are optimized for gaming and graphics (where shortcuts like these are invisible), not scientific computing. If your application demands accuracy, read the values using int2 coordinates (and NEAREST sampling) and do the interpolation in float. In my experience, it's not tons slower than using the texture interpolation since the same reads are happening, and memory bandwidth is usually the bottleneck (not compute).

Comment: Yes I gues memory bandwidth is the problem. To do tri-linear manually I have to call read_imagef 8x while using  CL_FILTER_LINEAR just 1x. But perhpas under the hood it still does those 8 reads (?) ... or maybe there is some cleaver trick how to do the read in more coherent way?

Comment: It still performs all those reads internally even with hardware filtering, but they'll generally be cached by the texture cache, which will also help with explicit filtering.

Comment: Exactly (the reads happen anyway, and the texture cache helps). We implemented software bilinear (because of an old bug that since got fixed) and it wasn't much slower than hardware bilinear. We also implemented software bicubic, and for 3D textures software tetrahedral (good for color management cubes).